# ¿Por qué cuando uso "\" en C# se me multiplica?

Tags: c#

Estoy queriendo acceder a una carpeta virtual, pero cuando quiero establecer el path todos los "" se me multiplican.

Quiero que el path sea "`\\carpetaVirtual\carpeta\archivo`" pero al multiplicarse me queda "`\\\\carpetavirtual\\carpeta\\archivo`". Estuve buscando en internet, foros y documentación pero no conseguí una explicación.

Es un proyecto C# ASP.NET MVC.

He intentado usar un `replace`

```
path = "//carpetaVirtual/carpeta/" + archivo;
path = path.replace("/", "\")
```

pero aunque me lo cambie se sigue multiplicando.

Así es lo único que estoy haciendo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Bilbit, me temo que tu error no puede ser reproducido. He puesto literalmente [tu código en este Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kDKDn7) y funciona normal. ¿Podrías reproducir el error en un Fiddle para poder ayudarte?

Comment: Jaime, tampoco eh podido replicarlo el problema en el Fiddle, pero dejo dos imagenes de lo que estoy haciendo. Hay un breakpoint ni bien pasa esas lineas. Es el unico lugar donde lo uso a "final", no se usa antes.

Comment: ves dos barras, porque la barra es el simbolo de escape de las cadenas, entonces al mostrarlo, lo muestra con dos barras... igual no deberia generarte problemas...

Comment: Osea que si tengo las 4 barras "\\\\"  es como si estuviese usando solamente 2?

Comment: Curioso que el debugger de visualStudio te muestre el valor en crudo. Yo personalmente uso Rider y te lo muestra como si fuera una salida en la consola, sin las barras duplicadas. Pero si @BilbitBolson, cuando ves \\ es como si hubiera una.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

las rutas se esciben con diagonales invertidas "\" (simbolo de escape para el compilador) pero estas estan reservadas por el idioma C# por ello necesitas escapar escribiendo otra "\" por lo cual nos quedaria "\\" entonces si quieres escribir una ruta debe de ser escrita de esta manera

```
string path = "\\carpetaVirtual\\carpeta\\archivo(Extension)"
```

Tambien puedes escribirla de esta manera, agregando una arroba al principio del string con esto le dices al compilador que estas escapando los caracteres reservados

```
 string path = @"\carpetaVirtual\carpeta\archivo(Extension)"
```

Si te fijas en este ejemplo [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
el compilador automaticamente le agrega otro "\" para escapar el caracter reservado "\" por ello cuando haces el **split("/","\")** el compilador metera otro "\" por cada "\" que tenga el string

Comment: Gracias! pero de hecho siempre me pide el @ al inicio..

Comment: Si no quieres usar la @ al principio, tienes que escapar cada diagonal invertida individualmente, por ejemplo:  string path = "\\carpetaVirtual\\carpeta\\archivo";

Comment: Ahh perfecto, ahora si lo entiendo, Muchas gracias Luis!